# Configuring 000-default.conf to develop multiple sites at once

Tags: server, configuration, drupal

I'm trying to develop multiple Drupal-based websites on my local machine using Ubuntu 14.3. So I have to edit my 000-default.conf file of course. When I edit it like so I'm able to work successfully with ONE site, but when I try to re-work it so I can develop multiple sites (with different code base) at the same time, it doesn't work right. Here's what I'm using successfully for single site development (relevant lines only included):

```
        ServerAdmin myemail.com
        ServerName localhost/sitename
        DocumentRoot /var/www/sitename

        [ more code ]

        <Directory /var/www/sitename>
          AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```

And this works fine to develop ONE site at a time. However, if I add more sites to my /var/www directory and change my 000-default.conf file to the following I get a mixture of errors.

One of the errors I get is that images no longer display correctly on the sites and show as placeholders. I'm referencing the images manually in my drupal code like so: /sites/default/files/filename.

The other I get is that the internal pages after the home page no longer work on my multiple sites when I do this. The home page shows fine (with image placeholders usually but not always) but when you click any links you get a Not Found error.

So here's the updated, incorrectly working 000-default.conf file:

```
ServerAdmin myemail.com
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www

[more code]

<Directory /var/www/sitename1>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/sitename2>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

So for now I have to use the first code (see at the top) and change it every time I want to work on a different site. There's gotta be a better way! right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fair amount more complex than that.
You actually need to create multiple .conf files and enable the virtual host using a2ensite.

[This guide should help you out.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts#step-four-%E2%80%94-create-new-virtual-host-files) Alternatively, try using software like [ServerPilot](https://www.serverpilot.io/?refcode=05c96a3f7359) to do this all automagically.